# xsl if condition with text or image

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement

I'm wondering how to replace a string say `AUD` with image if the text matches. I have this xsl code and not sure how to use if condition since I'm new to xsl coding.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table class="headingstable">
      <tr>
        <th class="headingstop">Title</th>
        <th class="headingstop">Country</th>
         <th class="headingstop">Date</th>

      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="weeklyevents/event">
    <tr>
      <td class="headingsmid"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td class="headingsmid"><xsl:value-of select="country"/></td>
      <td class="headingsmid"><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>

</xsl:template>
```

The country select can be one of the four in display results: USA, AUS, UK and JP. so I want to create an IF condition " **if string = UK then** `<img src="../uk.jpg" />`

I'm not sure how to do that, but tried many times like this:

```
<xsl:template match="country[. = 'UK']">
  <img src="../uk.jpg" />
</xsl:template>
```

how do I do that correctly??

**Update#1, this is my xml code:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <weeklyevents>
        <event>
            <title>AIG Services Index</title>
            <country>AUD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-04-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Bank Holiday</title>
            <country>JPY</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>MI Inflation Gauge m/m</title>
            <country>AUD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>ANZ Job Advertisements m/m</title>
            <country>AUD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Building Approvals m/m</title>
            <country>AUD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>HSBC Final Manufacturing PMI</title>
            <country>CNY</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Bank Holiday</title>
            <country>GBP</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Sentix Investor Confidence</title>
            <country>EUR</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>EU Economic Forecasts</title>
            <country>EUR</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>PPI m/m</title>
            <country>EUR</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Eurogroup Meetings</title>
            <country>EUR</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Final Services PMI</title>
            <country>USD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>ISM Non-Manufacturing PMI</title>
            <country>USD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Loan Officer Survey</title>
            <country>USD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Bank Holiday</title>
            <country>JPY</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-06-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Trade Balance</title>
            <country>AUD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-06-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Cash Rate</title>
            <country>AUD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-06-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>RBA Rate Statement</title>
            <country>AUD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-06-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Spanish Unemployment Change</title>
            <country>EUR</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-06-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Spanish Services PMI</title>
            <country>EUR</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-06-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Italian Services PMI</title>
            <country>EUR</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-06-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Final Services PMI</title>
            <country>EUR</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-06-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Services PMI</title>
            <country>GBP</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-06-2014]]></date>
        </event>
</weeklyevents>
```

Comment: you'll have to show your XML source too

Comment: ok, I will update my orignal question... Thanks

Comment: If you replace `<xsl:value-of select="country"/>` with `xsl:apply-templates select="country">` you will call the template you created.

Comment: but each country is different from the other i.e. US AU... how can I have an image for each in this case??

Comment: That is treated in each template. If you have one template for each image, as you described above, if it matches `UK` it will be called, otherwise (if it doesn't match) the default template will be called and it will simply print out the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change

```
<xsl:value-of select="country"/>
```

by

```
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="country = 'USA'">
            <img src="../usa.jpg" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="country = 'UK'">
            <img src="../uk.jpg" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            ...
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: I will try this code, too. Looks promising. Thanks@DaniCE

Answer (score 1):

If you want the template that includes the image tag to be processed, you should replace the `<xsl:value-of select="country"/>` with `xsl:apply-templates select="country">`. With that you will call the templates you defined for each country.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table class="headingstable">
        ...
        <xsl:for-each select="weeklyevents/event">
            <tr>
                <td class="headingsmid"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                <td class="headingsmid"><xsl:apply-templates select="country"/></td>
                <td class="headingsmid"><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

So if you have a template for each country, as you proposed, if there is `<country>UK</country>` in the source document, it will match one of your `country` templates:

```
<xsl:template match="country[. = 'UK']">
  <img src="../uk.jpg" />
</xsl:template>
```

and the generated `<td>` will be:

```
<td class="headingsmid">
     <img src="../uk.jpg"/>
</td>
```

In case the source contains an "unsupported" country (one you don't have a template for), it will simply print out the text:

```
<td class="headingsmid">AUS</td>
```

If you can derive your file name from the country code, then you can make your stylesheet even simpler.

If you are using **XSLT 2.0** replace all your `country` templates for:

```
<xsl:template match="country">
    <img src="../{lower-case(.)}.jpg" />
</xsl:template>
```

If you are limited to **XSLT 1.0** (if processing is done in a browser, for example), you won't have `lower-case()` but can use `translate()` like this:

```
<xsl:template match="country">
    <img src="../{translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')}.jpg" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: ok, quick question, where would the image go in this case? each country is different where each has different image..!!

Comment: The image is being placed inside the `<td class="headingsmid">...</td>` block.

Comment: The template matches any `country` element, and uses its contents to generate the image file name.

Comment: ok, say I want to apply an image to `<country>AUD</country>` only. what do I have to do?

Comment: In case you use the template above, there should exist an `../aud.jpg` image.

Comment: I wish I could mark your answer, too, as good answer. Thanks again. works great