# xsl merging same cells in one and convert time format

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

I'm having hard time figuring out how to merge the date cells in one like this example.
[image: merged dates]

### Part #1:

so the following dates in the xml as in my previous question [xsl-if-condition-with-text-or-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657062/xsl-if-condition-with-text-or-image) is like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <weeklyevents>
        <event>
            <title>AIG Services Index</title>
            <country>AUD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-04-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Bank Holiday</title>
            <country>JPY</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>MI Inflation Gauge m/m</title>
            <country>AUD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>ANZ Job Advertisements m/m</title>
            <country>AUD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Building Approvals m/m</title>
            <country>AUD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>HSBC Final Manufacturing PMI</title>
            <country>CNY</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Bank Holiday</title>
            <country>GBP</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Sentix Investor Confidence</title>
            <country>EUR</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>EU Economic Forecasts</title>
            <country>EUR</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>PPI m/m</title>
            <country>EUR</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Eurogroup Meetings</title>
            <country>EUR</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Final Services PMI</title>
            <country>USD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>ISM Non-Manufacturing PMI</title>
            <country>USD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Loan Officer Survey</title>
            <country>USD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-05-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Bank Holiday</title>
            <country>JPY</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-06-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Trade Balance</title>
            <country>AUD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-06-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Cash Rate</title>
            <country>AUD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-06-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>RBA Rate Statement</title>
            <country>AUD</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-06-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Spanish Unemployment Change</title>
            <country>EUR</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-06-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Spanish Services PMI</title>
            <country>EUR</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-06-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Italian Services PMI</title>
            <country>EUR</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-06-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Final Services PMI</title>
            <country>EUR</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-06-2014]]></date>
        </event>
        <event>
            <title>Services PMI</title>
            <country>GBP</country>
            <date><![CDATA[05-06-2014]]></date>
        </event>
</weeklyevents>
```

And my xsl code is this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table class="headingstable">
      <tr>
        <th class="headingstop">Title</th>
        <th class="headingstop">Country</th>
         <th class="headingstop">Date</th>

      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="weeklyevents/event">
    <tr>
      <td class="headingsmid"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td class="headingsmid"><xsl:value-of select="country"/></td>
      <td class="headingsmid"><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>

</xsl:template>
```

The expected results should be like the picture I posted above. so I want to merge only the same dates. maybe something like this **05-06-2014**

### Part #2:

Is it possible to convert the date to other formats such as **Thur 05-May** or **Thursday 05-06** instead of **05-06-2014**?

any idea how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate question regarding part #2, as it has nothing to do with the first part. Make sure to indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, as it makes a big difference (actually, you should always do that when asking about XSLT).

Comment: Re-reading your question, the first part is about **XSLT grouping**. This is one of the most often asked questions here, so do a search first. Here too, XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 makes a big difference.

Comment: Ok, it is xsl v.1, and I already searched for xslt grouping, but maybe because I'm new to this, I can't distinguish what the correct way to use... That's why I'm asking here again. I need at least a lead to that

Comment: In XSLT 1.0, the magic word is [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). After reading the article, you'll find hundreds of questions here using *[xslt] muenchian* as your search term.

Comment: Thanks@michael.hor257k. I even mixed up between merging and grouping previously so Thanks for the lead.

Comment: I have tried for hours since then and still not really working.. I need help!!

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried for hours since then and still not really working.. I
>   need help!!

Try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="events-by-date" match="event" use="date" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
    <!-- for each distinct date -->
        <xsl:for-each select="weeklyevents/event[count(. | key('events-by-date', date)[1]) = 1]">
        <tr>
            <th><xsl:value-of select="date"/></th>
        </tr>
                <!-- get events on this date -->
                <xsl:for-each select="key('events-by-date', date)">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks@michael for the lead. I could generate the table, but It is only one column where I want two columns. one column for dates and another for title. how do I do that?

Comment: @Digitalsite You are not new to SO, so you know how it works: you need to do *some* of the work yourself.

Comment: well, to be honest, I'm a new idiot to XSLT world so It might take me forever to understand how to do things correctly. I just started learning these stuff few days ago after finishing long time study on html, css and js thingy(s)... And I mentioned this before, If knew something, I wouldn't ask!!